# Xamarin - using AsBitmap() inside Glide Xamarin

Tags: android, xamarin.android, android-glide

I am using custom ImageView class to make my image zoomable , it work just fine with drawable , but I face issue when I am using it with Glide Library

I figure why this happen cause this custom class dont handle glide type so the solution to convert it to Bitmap

Link to [Solution](https://forums.xamarin.com/discussion/85888/how-can-i-load-an-url-into-a-custom-image-class-with-glide-or-picasso)

```
ScaleImageView img = new ScaleImageView(Context);
Glide.With(Context).Load(url).AsBitmap().Into(img);
```

but when I implement the same code I face issue with  `AsBitmap()` I cant find error reference

here my error message

```
 Error CS1061: Type `Com.Bumptech.Glide.DrawableTypeRequest' does not contain a definition for `AsBitmap' and no extension method `AsBitmap' of type `Com.Bumptech.Glide.DrawableTypeRequest' could be found. Are you missing an assembly reference? (CS1061)
```

Answer (score 1):

Use

```
Glide.With(Context).AsBitmap().Load(url).Into(img);
```

instead